# Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of a Veronese subring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

I've faced a problem while reading a paper. It is mentioned to be trivial but I couldn't prove it. I'd appreciate if you can lead me to some resources or if you can prove it for me. Thank you.

> Let $ S=K[X_1,X_2,X_3] $ be the polynomial ring with standard grading. The $c$th Veronese algebra of $S$ is $S^{(c)}=\bigoplus_{i}S_{ic}$. I know $S^{(c)}$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring. I need to use Hilbert function to prove that $\operatorname{reg}S^{(c)}\leq2$. Any other approach is also acceptable.

Comment: Can you please share which paper you are reading?

Comment: user26857, Manos
Your right I should have came up with more detail. 
I'm reading "Koszul Homology and Syzygies of Veronese Sub Algebras". The authors are Conca, Brunz and Romer.I've underestood every detail of the paper, except the part that I've asked. The paper considers it trivial in the proof of theorem 4.7. I introduced $T$ because $S^{(c)}$ is considered as $T-$ module and the regularity is actually $\operatorname{reg_{T}S^{(c)}}$. To your second question, $c\geq 3$ and is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy once you know few basis facts, such as:

1. $H^i_{\mathfrak m}(S)^{(c)}\simeq H^i_{\mathfrak m^{(d)}}(S^{(c)})$; see [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1240432552), Theorem 3.1.1.
2. $\operatorname{reg}S=0$.

We then have $H^i_{\mathfrak m^{(d)}}(S^{(c)})_j\simeq H^i_{\mathfrak m}(S)_{cj}$. The only $i$ that counts is $i=3$ (why?), and from 2. we have $H^3_{\mathfrak m}(S)_{cj}=0$ unless $cj\le -3$. Since $cj\le -3$ we get $j\le -1$, so $\operatorname{reg}S^{(c)}\le 2$.

Comment: We can generalize this to the following: If $S$ is a polynomial ring over a field in $n\ge 1$ indeterminates, then $\operatorname{reg}S^{(d)}\le n+\lfloor{-n/d}\rfloor$.